# SQL Server: after insert trigger for MS Access to be converted a stored proceduce

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures, triggers, odbc

I have an `after insert` trigger on my backend SQL Server; it is working great.

But it is not working for my front-end Microsoft Access when I fill the form, but it works when I fill it directly from the table.

Now I can is there a way that trigger to a stored procedure, but if there is any possibility of the trigger to work with my frontend then great wouldn't need the procedure.

I have 2 tables `FC_Fichas` and `FC_Fichas_Erros`.

Any suggestion on how to work through this.

Thanking you all in advance.

Below is the code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_Error] 
ON [dbo].[FC_Fichas]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    /*PFE10===============================PALUDISMO===============================================================*/
    /*Verificação CasosComFebrePaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM*/
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[FC_Fichas_Erros]
        SELECT 
            IDFicha, 
            CasosComFebrePaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM = 'TDRRealizadosPaludismoCriancas2A59Meses(M) não pode ser mayor que o CasosComFebrePaludismoCriancas2A59Meses(M)',
            CasosComFebrePaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM = 'Secção 4: Tratamento de Casos',
            CasosComFebrePaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM = 'CasosComFebrePaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM' 
        FROM 
            INSERTED
        WHERE 
            CasosComFebrePaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM < TDRRealizadosPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM

    /*Verificação CasosComFebrePaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF*/
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[FC_Fichas_Erros]
        SELECT 
            IDFicha, 
            CasosComFebrePaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF = 'TDRRealizadosPaludismoCriancas2A59Meses(F) não pode ser mayor que o CasosComFebrePaludismoCriancas2A59Meses(F)', 
            CasosComFebrePaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF = 'Secção 4: Tratamento de Casos',
            CasosComFebrePaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF = 'CasosComFebrePaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF' 
        FROM 
            INSERTED
        WHERE 
            CasosComFebrePaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF < TDRRealizadosPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF

    /*Verificação TDRPositivoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM*/
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[FC_Fichas_Erros]
        SELECT 
            IDFicha, 
            TDRPositivoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM = 'TDRPositivoPaludismoCriancas2A59Meses(M) não pode ser mayor que o TDRRealizadosPaludismoCriancas2A59Meses(M)',
            TDRPositivoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM = 'Secção 4: Tratamento de Casos',
            TDRPositivoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM = 'TDRPositivoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM' 
        FROM 
            INSERTED
        WHERE 
            TDRPositivoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM <> TDRRealizadosPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM

    /*Verificação TDRPositivoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF*/
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[FC_Fichas_Erros]
        SELECT 
            IDFicha, 
            TDRPositivoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF = 'TDRPositivoPaludismoCriancas2A59Meses(F) não pode ser mayor que o TDRRealizadosPaludismoCriancas2A59Meses(F)',
            TDRPositivoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF = 'Secção 4: Tratamento de Casos',
            TDRPositivoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF = 'TDRPositivoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF' 
        FROM 
            INSERTED
        WHERE 
            TDRPositivoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF <> TDRRealizadosPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF

    /*Verificação TDRNegativoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM*/
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[FC_Fichas_Erros]
        SELECT 
            IDFicha, 
            TDRNegativoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM = 'TDRNegativoPaludismoCriancas2A59Meses(M) não pode ser mayor que o TDRNegativoPaludismoCriancas2A59Meses(M)',
            TDRNegativoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM = 'Secção 4: Tratamento de Casos',
            TDRNegativoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM = 'TDRNegativoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM' 
        FROM 
            INSERTED
        WHERE 
            TDRNegativoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM <> TDRRealizadosPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesM

    /*Verificação TDRNegativoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF*/
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[FC_Fichas_Erros]
        SELECT 
            IDFicha, 
            TDRNegativoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF = 'TDRNegativoPaludismoCriancas2A59Meses(F) não pode ser mayor que o TDRNegativoPaludismoCriancas2A59Meses(F)',
            TDRNegativoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF = 'Secção 4: Tratamento de Casos',
            TDRNegativoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF = 'TDRNegativoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF' 
        FROM 
            INSERTED
        WHERE 
            TDRNegativoPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF <> TDRRealizadosPaludismoCriancas2A59MesesF
END
```

Comment: Yes you could capture this logic in a stored procedure. To get recently inserted values like this you could use the OUTPUT clause. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: The Access form works directly with the table? You can use some temp table in access that gets data from the form, then user press Submit on the form and insertion occurs, in that case trigger should work well. Another way is to pass data from form into SP.

Comment: Yes they are working directly. i have a master table (FC_Fichas) with over 100 colums, so my form for that table is divided into 8 section meaning i have 8 form that are all pointing to that table. user

Comment: the user first have to fill the first form then (click section 2 button) which will take him or her to form 2, and on form 2 you have (section 3 button) which will open form 3 so it continues until the end. after insert trigger is not working in this case  But then if  I go to form 2  property sheet (data) and change the dataentry (yes) trigger will work but it will save as a different record from the first form.